# doParallel:::doParallelSNOW complains when foreach(..., .export) is specified

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, doparallel

I'm curious what the design argument for `doParallel:::doParallelSNOW()` giving a warning when globals are explicitly specified in `.export` could be?  For example,

```
library("doParallel")
registerDoParallel(cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2L))

a <- 1
y <- foreach(i = 1L, .export = "a") %dopar% { 2 * a }
## Warning in e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data) :
##  already exporting variable(s): a
```

Is it possible to disable above warnings in doParallel?

I'd argue that such a warning would suggest the user/developer *not* to specify `.export` and rely fully on foreach adaptors to take care of globals.  However, the success of identification of globals differ among adaptors.

Package versions: doParallel 1.0.11, iterators 1.0.9, foreach 1.4.4

**CLARIFICATION 2018-01-14**: [These warnings occur after doParallel first having identified globals automatically and then appending the ones the developer list in `.export`](https://github.com/cran/doParallel/blob/b843662b9c49fb610434ae22713fbc188a06b1c3/R/doParallel.R#L414-L434) - my question is on why it doesn't not accept the deliberate choice that was done by the developer? Warning about correct globals is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I may have a solution but I wouldn't recommend to do what you're asking in the first place.

Anyway, if you enclose your `foreach` call in another function, `a` wouldn't be found in the direct environment of the `foreach` call so that it wouldn't be exported automatically.

```
library("doParallel")
registerDoParallel(cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2L))

a <- 1
foreach2 <- function() {
  foreach(i = 1L, .export = "a") %dopar% { 2 * a }
}
y <- foreach2()
```

Comment: A real use case is `caret`, which does not specify `.export`.  (I'm not sure if this is because caret is fine tuned for doParallel only, or that is the official foreach approach - "don't specify `.export`").  If [one specify globals explicitly](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/caret/commit/54fc61a331fde4cb9910c06cfc6393d1d40b4939), then one get the warning in my original question.

Comment: Thanks Florian, I've reread my original question and realized it was not clear - I've updated with a clarification at the end.  Yes, tricking `foreach::getexports()` to fail to detect `a` as a global would avoid the warning and I agree it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is simply remove `.export = "a"` then the warning gone since the warning just said `.export` redundantly exports the `a` object.

Comment: The problem with that approach is **foreach** fails to find some globals in some cases, which means it's a trial and error game.  Unfortunately, this also depends on whether you put the code in a script or in a package, so there's no one-solution fits everything. The main reason for my question was to inquire on the design choice and whether it was intentional or not.  FWIW, there's been discussion to modernize how **foreach** finds globals, cf. https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/foreach/issues/2